# Утечка памяти при работе со строками

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

В конструкции происходит утечка памяти:

```
str := 'ABC';
str := Copy(str, 1, Length(str) - 1);
```

Как это избежать?
Избежать элегантно (для рекурсивного использовния)?

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HPStart: THeapStatus;
  HPEnd: THeapStatus;
  lost: LongInt;
  str: AnsiString;

begin
  HPStart := GetHeapStatus;

  str := 'ASD';
  str := Copy(str, 1, Length(str) - 1);


  HPEnd := GetHeapStatus;
  lost := HPEnd.TotalAllocated - HPStart.TotalAllocated;
  Edit1.Text := str + ' ' + IntToStr(lost);
end;
```

Lost - 32б. ОС - Windows

Comment: Уточните, в чем вы тут видите утечку памяти?

Comment: @Alex Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте код туда.

Comment: А как вы уверены в том, что по выходу из функции память не возвращается? А комментарий можете удалить.

Comment: Не используйте присвоение переменной в себя; Вместо этого пишите типа: Str1 := Copy(str ...)

Comment: Да. Был не прав. Исправлюсь

Comment: @santavital это никак не влияет на работу программы. Тем более утечек памяти в данном коде нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибочно полагать, что в данном примере произойдёт утечка памяти.
В строках реализован подсчёт ссылок, и при выходе из программы вся выделенная память будет удалена.
Чтобы в этом убедиться, включите в отладчике отслеживание утечек памяти в настройках проекта: меню `Project->Project Options->Compiler Options->Debugging->OtherDebugging info->Use Heaptrc unit(check for mem-leaks)(-gh)`.
После выхода из программы получите окно с подобным сообщением:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Heap dump by heaptrc unit

2098 memory blocks allocated : 1888393/1895256

2098 memory blocks freed     : 1888393/1895256

0 unfreed memory blocks : 0

True heap size : 688128 (112 used in System startup)

True free heap : 688016


---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------
```

Обратите внимание на надпись `0 unfreed memory blocks : 0`; это значит, что нет неосвобождённой памяти.